# Result of operator - is unused swift reduce

Tags: swift, reduce

I try to use reduce function in Swift.

```
taken = basket.reduce(into: 0) { (initial, bi) in
            initial + bi.amount() - bi.discount()
        }
```

However i got an error: `Result of operator '-' is unused.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two similar `reduce` methods: In

```
func reduce<Result>(into initialResult: Result, _ updateAccumulatingResult: (inout Result, Element) throws -> ()) rethrows -> Result
```

the closure updates the accumulator, but does not return a value, whereas in

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

the closure returns the updated accumulated value.

In your case it should be

```
taken = basket.reduce(into: 0) { (initial, bi) in
        // Update accumulated value:
        initial += bi.amount() - bi.discount()
    }
```

using the first version, or

```
taken = basket.reduce(0) { (initial, bi) in
        // Compute and return accumulated value:
        return initial + bi.amount() - bi.discount()
    }
```

using the second version.